# Azure B2C - Multiple accounts created with external identity providers with same email

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an application with Azure B2C for user identity, and I have also configured login via Facebook.

Logging in via Facebook creates a new account, even if the email was previously used to register via azure flow.

Is there any option to not create a new account when logging in via third-party providers, but just simply log in to the account with the given address instead of creating a new one?

Answer (score 0):

In B2C, logging in via federation (which includes social) creates a "shadow account", which is separate from the user's local account.

If you want to combine the two accounts, you can [link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#account-linking) them.

Comment: This look like excaly what i want for me.
But im not able to finish initial setup.

I assume that I have problem with this:
"You will be asked to sign in. Make sure to sign in with an Azure AD Work Or School account residing in the directory with Global Admin rights to the B2C tenant.
It will not work with Microsoft Personal accounts."

Any option, to use run this with my personal account?

Comment: What initial setup?

Comment: check:
https://b2ciefsetupapp.azurewebsites.net/Home/Experimental?sampleFolderName=auto-account-linking

Comment: No. You must have had a work account to set up the Azure AD tenant? Use that.